# Which one of these ways to send bytes through sockets is faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I'm sending a lot of data with this, so it's important to make it as fast as possible.

```
file = open("somefile.anything", "rb")
data = file.read(1024)
while(data):
    s.send(data)
    data = file.read(1024)
```

This is what I'm using right now, but I was wondering if this solution would be faster: Sending more bytes at once.

```
file = open("somefile.anything", "rb")
data = file.read(4096)
while(data):
    s.send(data)
    data = file.read(4096)
```

Or maybe there is no difference between the two?

Comment: Data corruption can happen if you do not check the `socket.send` return value. Use `socket.sendall` instead.

Comment: @VPfB Will do, thaks for the advice

Comment: Note that "faster" sometimes benefits from out of the box thinking. I used to need to transport large amounts of video. The fastest way was to load physical media on a large truck.